# Angular 4 - How to route to a particular component when back button is pressed?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to route to a particular path when the <kbd>back</kbd> button will be clicked in the browser.

I was trying the following code snippet. But it changes the URL to the desired one for just a moment, and then routing to the previous actual URL.

```
constructor(location: PlatformLocation, private router: Router) {
    location.onPopState(() => {
        router.navigate(['/home']);
    });
}
```

Comment: The question should be : why I want change a behaviour to what  users are used to, as all devices have a certain behaviour. Like, would you like to find out that on google.com when you refresh your research, it takes you to your gmail page ?

Comment: Actually, I want to build an angular webapp which looks like an android app (using webview). So I need to explicitly declare the back key press event.

Comment: If you want an android app then you make an android native app, when you do an angular App it should look like a web app which could be run in an mobile device. That's it. Don't reinvent the wheel and don't confuse the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution in some different way and using JavaScript.

Suppose I am currently in "/menu" and I want to navigate to "/home" when the back button will be pressed. Check the following code snippet.

```
ngOnInit() {
window.history.pushState( {} , 'Home', '/home' );
window.history.pushState( {} , 'Menu', '/menu' ); }
```

Here I am pushing two states in window.history inside `ngOnInit()`. Firstly the URL `(/home)` I want to visit on the back key press and then the current URL `(/menu)`.

It is working well and I had achieved what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to put a listener on the top level like:

```
  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
```

and do

```
  router.navigate(['/home']);
```

inside.

Comment: Just wondering, in this case, how to prevent router navigation?

Comment: The same problem is here also. @PankajParkar rightly pointed that it is not preventing router navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use routerLink

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

```
<a [routerLink]="['/main']">
 <b> < BACK </b>
</a>
```